# what are Javascript lexical environment object's correct components?

Tags: javascript, theory, lexical

When I read about the lexical environment object in this link https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0

it says that the lexical environment has a "this binding",

> Each Lexical Environment has three components:
>
> 1. Environment Record,
> 2. Reference to the outer environment,
> 3. This binding.

every other article that I have read says that It doesnt have a "this binding", which is it? and can someone point me to a book that I can buy that is the best book made by the creators of javascript so I can get correct information. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest finding a better blog post or article.  That post ignores how block scope binding works in modern JavaScript, so it's really incomplete.

Comment: It does have a `this` binding, but only arrow functions search for `this` in inherited lexical scopes.